# why is ipopt not optimising properly - non linear site allocation?

Tags: pyomo

I am currently working on optimizing route allocation involving 2 origin points & 2 end points. Each route has a freight cost $/t. However the origin point has a set flag-fall fee which is activated as soon as there are tonnes allocated.  This adds some non-linearity to the problem which prompted me to using the Ipopt solver in pyomo. I have set up the cost function for the objective value per below.

For some reason, it always opens both origin points despite the flag-fall cost being prohibitive over the freight costs. I am not sure if the problem is set up correctly? Or if Ipopt is suited to problems like these.

```
sites = ['A','B']
phys = {'A':100,'B':100}
demand = {'F':50,'G':10}
dest = ['F','G']

routes = [(s,d) for s in sites for d in dest]
ops_costs = {'A':1000, 'B':1000}
freight_costs = {('A','F'): 9, ('B','F'): 8.6, ('A','G'):10, ('B','G'):12}

model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(sites,dest,within=NonNegativeReals)

obj2={}
for s in sites:
    obj2[s] = sum(model.x[s,d] for d in dest)

model.freight = sum(freight_costs[s,d]*model.x[s,d] for (s,d) in routes)
model.flagfall = sum((ops_costs[s]*obj2[s])/(obj2[s]+0.0001) for s in sites)
value = Objective(expr=model.freight+model.flagfall,sense=minimize)

model.cons = ConstraintList()
for s in sites:
    site_alloc = 0
    for d in dest:
        site_alloc = site_alloc + model.x[s,d]
    model.cons.add(site_alloc<=phys[s])

for d in dest:
    demand_alloc = 0
    for s in sites:
        demand_alloc = demand_alloc + model.x[s,d]
    model.cons.add(demand_alloc==demand[d])

SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(model, tee=True)
```

Comment: Does IPOPT report that it found an optimal solution? Did you double check your model using `model.pprint()` to verify that all constraints and objective are what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it does report the following message, "EXIT: Optimal Solution Found."  However, the route allocations don't seem to make sense when the ops_costs are modified. It seems to not optimise properly for the ops_costs which is like a fixed cost once tonnes are allocated from a particular site (this calculation is done by obj2 variable). For example when I make ops_costs for Site B small in comparison to A. It allocates tonnes to site A rather than B the cheaper site.

Comment: I am not sure if it is an issue with the way my objective function is set up or that the cost surface for this problem is choppy from 0 tonne to 1 tonne after which is smooth.  Thanks for looking into to this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem would be better posed as MINLP, in which case you will need to use Bonmin, Couenne, or another suitable solver.

Comment: I did try Bonmin & Couenne but could not get it to solve.
With Bonmin - I keep getting a message saying 'The LP relaxation is infeasible or too expensive.'  Even though I have double checked my problem and it solves with Ipopt (just not optimally).  
With Couenne - 'Problem Size before reformulation 4 variables, 4 constraints.  Problem size after reformuation 11 variables, 2 constraints.  
Maybe I need to go over the math on how the above 2 solvers solve.